# Convert Spark Structured DataFrame to Pandas using pandas_udf

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I need to read csv files as stream and then convert that to `pandas dataframe`.

Here is what I have done so far

```py
    DataShema = StructType([ StructField("TimeStamp", LongType(), True), \
    StructField("Count", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("Reading", FloatType(), True) ])

    group_columns = ['TimeStamp','Count','Reading']

    @pandas_udf(DataShema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
    def get_pdf(pdf):
        return pd.DataFrame([pdf[group_columns]],columns=[group_columns])

    # getting Surge data from the files
    SrgDF = spark \
        .readStream \
        .schema(DataShema) \
        .csv("ProcessdedData/SurgeAcc")

    mydf = SrgDF.groupby(group_columns).apply(get_pdf)

    qrySrg = SrgDF \
        .writeStream \
        .format("console") \
        .start() \
        .awaitTermination()
```

I believe from another source ([Convert Spark Structure Streaming DataFrames to Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55008433/convert-spark-structure-streaming-dataframes-to-pandas-dataframe)) that converting structured streaming dataframe to pandas is not directly possible and it seems that pandas_udf is the right approach but cannot figure out exactly how to achieve this. I need the pandas dataframe to pass into my functions.

***Edit***

when I run the code (changing the query to `mydf` rather than `SrgDF`) then I get the following error: `pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: 'Writing job aborted.\n=== Streaming Query ===\nIdentifier: [id = 18a15e9e-9762-4464-b6d1-cb2db8d0ac41, runId = e3da131e-00d1-4fed-82fc-65bf377c3f99]\nCurrent Committed Offsets: {}\nCurrent Available Offsets: {FileStreamSource[file:/home/mls5/Work_Research/Codes/Misc/Python/MachineLearning_ArtificialIntelligence/00_Examples/01_ApacheSpark/01_ComfortApp/ProcessdedData/SurgeAcc]: {"logOffset":0}}\n\nCurrent State: ACTIVE\nThread State: RUNNABLE\n\nLogical Plan:\nFlatMapGroupsInPandas [Count#1], get_pdf(TimeStamp#0L, Count#1, Reading#2), [TimeStamp#10L, Count#11, Reading#12]\n+- Project [Count#1, TimeStamp#0L, Count#1, Reading#2]\n   +- StreamingExecutionRelation FileStreamSource[file:/home/mls5/Work_Research/Codes/Misc/Python/MachineLearning_ArtificialIntelligence/00_Examples/01_ApacheSpark/01_ComfortApp/ProcessdedData/SurgeAcc], [TimeStamp#0L, Count#1, Reading#2]\n'
19/05/20 18:32:29 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Stopped by driver
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyarrow/__init__.py:152: UserWarning: pyarrow.open_stream is deprecated, please use pyarrow.ipc.open_stream
  warnings.warn("pyarrow.open_stream is deprecated, please use "`.

***EDIT-2***

Here is the code to reproduce the error

```py
import sys

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import Row, SparkSession, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

from pyspark.sql.types import *

import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
import pyarrow as pa

import glob

#####################################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("RealTimeIMUAnalysis") \
        .getOrCreate() 

    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")

    # reduce verbosity
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    ##############################################################################

    # using the saved files to do the Analysis
    DataShema = StructType([ StructField("TimeStamp", LongType(), True), \
    StructField("Count", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("Reading", FloatType(), True) ])

    group_columns = ['TimeStamp','Count','Reading']

    @pandas_udf(DataShema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
    def get_pdf(pdf):
        return pd.DataFrame([pdf[group_columns]],columns=[group_columns])

    # getting Surge data from the files
    SrgDF = spark \
        .readStream \
        .schema(DataShema) \
        .csv("SurgeAcc")

    mydf = SrgDF.groupby('Count').apply(get_pdf)
    #print(mydf)

    qrySrg = mydf \
        .writeStream \
        .format("console") \
        .start() \
        .awaitTermination()
```

To run, you need to create a folder named `SurgeAcc` where the code is and create a csv file inside with the following format:

```
TimeStamp,Count,Reading
1557011317299,45148,-0.015494
1557011317299,45153,-0.015963
1557011319511,45201,-0.015494
1557011319511,45221,-0.015494
1557011315134,45092,-0.015494
1557011315135,45107,-0.014085
1557011317299,45158,-0.015963
1557011317299,45163,-0.015494
1557011317299,45168,-0.015024`
```

Comment: If you are using pandas_udf (for GROUPED_MAP), the input to the function will be pandas dataframe and output is also pandas dataframe . I don't see any issue here. Are you facing any issues?

Comment: The error message is too long, so I add as an Edit to my message.

Comment: Please update with sample data also, that helps in troubleshooting for others. It could be data issue also.

Comment: @RangaVure I have just edited my question with the code and data that would reproduce the error. I would really appreciate your feedback. Just to add further, the reason I am using Structured Streaming (rather than static read) is that the csv file will constantly get updated by another stream

Answer (score 0):

Your return pandas_udf dataframe is not matching with the schema specified.

Please note that input to the pandas_udf will be pandas dataframe and also returns pandas dataframe.

You can use all pandas functions inside the pandas_udf. Only thing you have to make sure is the ReturnDataShema should match with actual output of the function.

```
ReturnDataShema = StructType([StructField("TimeStamp", LongType(), True), \
                            StructField("Count", IntegerType(), True), \
                            StructField("Reading", FloatType(), True), \
                            StructField("TotalCount", FloatType(), True)])

@pandas_udf(ReturnDataShema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
    def get_pdf(pdf):
        # This following stmt is causing schema mismatch
        # return pd.DataFrame([pdf[group_columns]],columns=[group_columns])
        # If you want to return all the rows of pandas dataframe
        # you can simply
        # return pdf
        # If you want to do any aggregations, you can do like the below, or use pandas query
        # but make sure the return pandas dataframe complies with ReturnDataShema
        total_count = pdf['Count'].sum()
        return pd.DataFrame([(pdf.TimeStamp[0],pdf.Count[0],pdf.Reading[0],total_count)])
```